Jsoup Java get a specific td available-day
I have the following code:
Document doc =
    Jsoup.connect("https://dgpci.mai.gov.ro/drpciv-booking/formular/35/vehicleFirstRegistration")
         .get();
Elements tds = doc.select("table.calendar-table tbody tr td.col-sm-1.available-day");
for (Element e : tds) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}

I need to print the first day with classes: col-sm-1 and available-day.


<div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="calendar-wrap">
    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="calendar-navigation"><a _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="prev"
            data-calendar-nav="prev"><i _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="nc-icon nc-tail-right"></i></a>
        <h3 _ngcontent-uds-c6="">Iunie 2024</h3><a _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="next" data-calendar-nav="next"><i
                _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="nc-icon nc-tail-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="public-portal-calendar">
        <table _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="calendar-table">
            <tr _ngcontent-uds-c6=""><!---->
                <th _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 title-label"> Lu </th>
                <th _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 title-label"> Ma </th>
                <th _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 title-label"> Mi </th>
                <th _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 title-label"> Jo </th>
                <th _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 title-label"> Vi </th>
                <th _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 title-label"> Sa </th>
                <th _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 title-label"> Du </th>
            </tr><!---->
            <tr _ngcontent-uds-c6=""><!---->
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">27</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">28</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">29</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">30</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">31</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">1</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">2</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-uds-c6=""><!---->
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">3</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">4</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">5</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">6</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">7</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">8</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">9</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-uds-c6=""><!---->
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">10</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">11</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">12</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="selected-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">13</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">14</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">15</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">16</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-uds-c6=""><!---->
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">17</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">18</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">19</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">20</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">21</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">22</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">23</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-uds-c6=""><!---->
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">24</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">25</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">26</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">27</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 available-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">28</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">29</div>
                </td>
                <td _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="col-sm-1 busy-day">
                    <div _ngcontent-uds-c6="" class="day">30</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>




HTML fetched by jsoup Java code in your example does not match the HTML you have pasted bellow.

"I need to print the first day with classes: col-sm-1 and available-day." - I am not sure I understand your question. Your CSS selector seems to return the correct results for the HTML snippet you have pasted. If you don't want all days in the calendar that match your query, you can call selectFirst() instead of select() and remove the for loop from your code.

I need to display the first day that has available-day
for this I need to search the calendar in the current month as well as in the coming months, then display the first day that there is availability
I just get an error
Calendar not found.
the page has reCAPTCHA, probably for this reason it does not display the calendar  Do you have any solution?
